# How can I Add Search View in Toolbar Android?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

How to add Search view in toolbar in Android?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#2196F3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <EditText
           <--TODO your code-->
        />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```